# How can I set focus on "Faculty Name" textbox on page load for the following Razor code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Faculty Name *</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.FacultyName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Technician e.t.c", @name = "txtfacultyname" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.FacultyName, "", new { @class = "error" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>EmailAddress *</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "abc@abc.com", @name = "txtemailaddress" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "error" })
                    </div>
```

In my Code I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
  $(".form:first").focus();
});
```

Comment: Better use `$('.form-control]name="txtfacultyname"]').focus();

Answer (score 0):

You could use @Tariq option in the comments or if you just want the first input:

```
$(function () {       
  $(".form input:first").focus();
});
```

Or even target formcontrol

```
$(function () {       
  $(".form .form-control:first").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class name for "Faculty Name" textbox is `form-control` not `form`. So use that selector to focus on it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".form-control:first").focus(); 
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form-control[name="txtfacultyname"]').focus();
```

or first input

```
$('.form-control input:first').focus();
```